# How to mount LUKS/EXT4 disk in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, encryption, ext4, luks

I used the defaults in `cryptsetup` to create an encrypted disk with EXT4:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda # list property luks 
LUKS header information for /dev/sda

Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    xts-plain64
Hash spec:      sha256
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      8e ef dc 93 fc f5 17 87 fc a4 20 46 82 83 8a 8d 8d bb 94 99 
MK salt:        7f 01 e9 66 b8 bf 7b b9 a2 02 c2 11 71 a2 69 af 
                e9 ab e7 d7 cb 8b 02 91 b7 9a fb 9a ed 62 bc c6 
MK iterations:  264500
UUID:           0179e7de-a468-4213-b932-ee2df135336d

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
        Iterations:             2133332
        Salt:                   f0 60 58 ec 13 0b 9e 30 0b cf 9a af a5 22 6f 9d 
                                ff 52 9f c4 b8 29 03 54 49 69 bf a4 ad a4 8a 2a 
        Key material offset:    8
        AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
Key Slot 3: DISABLED
Key Slot 4: DISABLED
Key Slot 5: DISABLED
Key Slot 6: DISABLED
Key Slot 7: DISABLED
$ mount | grep encrypted
/dev/mapper/encrypted on /media/encrypted type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

How do I identify this disk and configure [ext2fs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/ext2.html)/[ExtFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/)/other plus [LibreCrypt](https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt)/other in Windows 7? I tried some settings with ext2fs and LibreCrypt, but the latter always refuses to recognise the disk.

Comment: Is LibreCrypt failing to see the underlying filesystem (EXT4) or the crypt container itself?